# Custom component ExtJS, not work setValue

Tags: javascript, extjs4

anybody, please help me with created component for extjs 4.2

```
Ext.define('mycomponent', {
    extend:'Ext.form.field.Display',
    alias: 'widget.mycomponent',

    initComponent: function() {
        this.setValue("some value") // not setup
        this.callParent(arguments);
        console.log(this)
    },

})
```

i try

```
Ext.getCmp(this.id).setValue("some")
```

but html object do not exist, events beforerender e.t.c. not running. how i can set value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fully working example, tested with 4.2.1.

```
Ext.define('Foo', {
    extend:'Ext.form.field.Display',
    alias: 'widget.mycomponent',

    initComponent: function() {
        this.setValue("some value") // not setup
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
})

Ext.onReady(function() {

    new Foo({
        renderTo: document.body
    })

});
```

Comment: if i set "name" property, how i can get it on initComponent method?

Comment: `var name = this.name;`

Comment: but i need get value of name, this field in form, and i bind form from backend (ajax)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the getValue() and setValue() methods in your constructor in order to work.

```
getValue: function () {
        var me = this,
            value;
        return value;
    }

    setValue: function (value) {
        var me = this;

// Example only should't work as it is
        me.displayField.setValue(value);
    }
```